# How to produce an Itten color star?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, generative-art

Johannes Itten (1888 - 1967) was a Swiss painter and designer

[image]

From 1919 to 1922, Itten taught at the Bauhaus School in Weimar, teaching his students the basics of materials, composition and color. One of his better-known works from this period is the color star of 1921:

[image]

Color wheels and stars have a long tradition, which is explained in this excellent post by David Briggs:

[huevaluechroma](http://www.huevaluechroma.com/072.php)

Another table from David's post:

[image]

Also interesting:
[colorsystem](https://www.colorsystem.com/?page_id=762&lang=en)

To replicate the Itten star I tried `RadialAxisPlot`, but don't have any idea how to color the 12 different segments (spikes) differently.

```
RadialAxisPlot[Riffle[Table[1, 12], 0.5, {2, -1, 2}], 
 FillingStyle -> 
  RadialGradientFilling[{ImageScaled[0], ImageScaled[0.25], ImageScaled[1]} -> {Darker @ Red, Brown , Black}], 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> True, "GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]

I would like to see "warm" colors, not the usual "glaring" hue colors. More Itten and less Holzel, so to speak.

Comment: I'm much fond of the "C, Sowerby, 1809" chart, any idea how to reproduce it faithfully?

Comment: Yes, it's very nice, but would require a new question. Have a look a this link: https://www.colorsystem.com/?page_id=762&lang=en

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very interesting reading!

Comment: Straight off-topic, but I must comment here as a thanks: thanks to this question, I turned out to read/watched and learned a lot about how to mix and use watercolor pigments. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ittenColors = Riffle[#, Blend /@ Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, 1}]] & @ 
  {Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple};


Row[Map[Style[#, 50] &] @ ittenColors, Spacer[2]]
```

[image]

We can use [`PieChart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PieChart.html) with a custom [`ChartElementFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html) as follows:

```
ClearAll[colorStar]
colorStar[rsegments_ : 12, radialorigin_ : 0] := 
  Module[{segs = Partition[Subdivide[## & @@ #[[2]], rsegments], 2, 1], 
     poly = Polygon[Join[{{0, 0}}, 
      Through[{Mean, Last, Mean} @ #[[2]]] 
      Transpose @ Through @ {Cos, Sin} @ Riffle[#[[1]], Mean @ #[[1]]]]]}, 
    Map[r |-> 
       {Blend[{White, Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"], Black}, 
         Rescale[First @ r, radialorigin + {0, 1}]], 
        ChartElementData["Sector"][{#[[1]], r}, ##2] /. 
         p_Polygon :> RegionIntersection[poly, p]}] @ segs] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
PieChart[Table[1, 12],  
 ChartStyle -> ittenColors,
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
 SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/6, -1}, 0},
 PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], Subdivide[12]},
 ChartElementFunction -> colorStar[]]
```

[image]

```
PieChart[Table[1, 12],  
 ChartStyle -> ittenColors,
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
 SectorOrigin -> {{Pi/6, -1}, 1/4},
 ChartElementFunction -> colorStar[12, 1/4],
 PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], 1/4 + Subdivide[12]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Itten's 1921 color scheme:

```
clist = {{156, 72, 83}, {183, 54, 62}, {218, 64, 67}, {252, 83, 
    55}, {254, 154, 46}, {255, 226, 78}, {198, 189, 58}, {77, 146, 
    100}, {1, 114, 127}, {0, 105, 156}, {62, 96, 167}, {97, 88, 133}};
RadialAxisPlot[
 Table[RotateRight[PadRight[{0.5, 1.0, 0.5}, 24], 2 n], {n, 0, 11}], 
 Filling -> 
  Table[{Axis, 
    RadialGradientFilling[
     Table[ImageScaled[s], {s, 0.1, 0.9, 1/6*(8/10)}] -> 
      Table[Blend[{White, c, Black}, x], {x, 0, 1, 1/6}]]}, {c, 
    RGBColor /@ (clist/255)}], 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> True, "GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Gray, Thin], 
 GridLines -> Table[i, {i, 1/7, 1, 1/7}], Ticks -> None, 
 Axes -> Riffle[Table[False, 20], True, {1, -2, 6}], PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

Itten's 1961 color scheme:

```
clist = {{120, 7, 77}, {217, 1, 13}, {250, 38, 1}, {247, 93, 9}, {246,
     143, 1}, {247, 185, 4}, {114, 155, 20}, {3, 134, 95}, {1, 136, 
    182}, {2, 75, 158}, {3, 48, 141}, {20, 26, 125}};
```

[image]