# Reproducing two of Victor Vasarely's colored cuboids (Eroed-Per and Gestalt-Bleu)

Tags: graphics, color, generative-art, polygons

Victor Vasarely (1906 - 1997) was a Hungarian-French artist. He is, along with Bridget Riley, the best-known representative of Op Art (optical art). Based on the
 [color experiments of the Bauhaus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292584/how-to-produce-an-itten-color-star), he developed abstract works that often create optical illusions.

[image]

*Victor Vasarely, Eroed-Per, 1978*

In 1928, Vasarely enrolled at Műhely, then widely recognized as Budapest's center of Bauhaus studies. The first geometric
abstractions based on squares were created. The square bubble shown below is an almost perfect reproduction by `cvgmt` of Vasarely's `Terz` (1979) with just a few lines of
[Mathematica code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297114/how-can-we-produce-sliceforms) :

[image]

Vasarely settled in Paris in 1930, where he worked as a graphic artist and as a creative consultant at advertising agencies. He designed the 1972 logo for Renault.

[image]

The Vasarely Foundation in Aix-en-Provence is a museum housed in a distinct structure designed by Vasarely. It was inaugurated in 1976 by French president Georges Pompidou.

[image]

**My request**

I would like to reproduce with Mathematica *Eroed-per* (first from above) or *Gestalt-Bleu 1976* (shown below). Thank you in advance for your ideas and contributions.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Eroed-Per

[image]

**Seed polygon coordinates:**

```
coords = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};

{coords2, coords3, coords4, coords5} = 
  MapApply[ShearingTransform[45 Degree, ## & @@ #[{#2 {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]] @ 
    coords &] @
  {{Identity, 1}, {Reverse, -1}, {Reverse, 1}, {Identity, -1}};

Row[Graphics[Polygon @ #, AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ 
  {coords, coords2,  coords3, coords4, coords5}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{Opacity[.3], 
  MapThread[{#, Polygon@#2} &]@
  {{Red, Green, Blue, Cyan}, 
   {coords2, coords3, coords4, coords5}}, 
 EdgeForm[{Thick, Gray}], FaceForm[], Polygon @ coords}]
```

[image]

**Texturing polygons:**

```
ClearAll[bands, texturedPolygon]

bands[col_, n_ : 10] := Texture @ Rasterize @
   Graphics[Raster[Table[Table[List @@ Blend[{Black, col}, x], n],
     {x, Rest @ Subdivide[n]}]], 
   PlotRangePadding -> None]

texturedPolygon[coords_, color_ : Automatic, origin_ : Bottom, n_ : 10] :=
 {bands[color /. Automatic -> LightGray, n], 
  Polygon[RotateLeft[coords, 
    origin /. {Bottom -> 0, Top -> 2, Left -> 1, Right -> 3}],
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}
```

***Examples:***

```
Multicolumn[
 MapApply[Graphics[texturedPolygon[#2, RandomColor[], #], 
     ImageSize -> 1 -> 100] &] @
  Tuples[{ {Bottom, Top, Right, Left}, {coords, coords3, coords4}}], 
 Appearance -> "Vertical"]
```

[image]

**Translation and styling of seed polygons:**

```
magenta = {{{0, 0}, coords, #, Bottom}, 
  {{0, 2}, coords5, #, Bottom},
  {{2, -1}, coords, #, Bottom}, 
  {{-2, 1}, coords, #, Top}, 
  {{1, -2}, coords5, #, Top}, 
  {{2, 0}, coords4, #, Right}, 
  {{-2, -1}, coords4, #, Right}, 
  {{1, 2}, coords, #,  Left}, 
  {{-1, -2}, coords, #, Left}} & @ Lighter[Magenta];

yellow = {{{1, 1}, coords2, #, Bottom}, 
  {{-2, -1}, coords2, #, Top}, 
  {{-1, 1}, coords3, #, Right}, 
  {{0, -2}, coords4, #, Right}, 
  {{1, 0}, coords3, #, Left}, 
  {{0, 1}, coords4, #, Left}} & @ Yellow;

gray = {{{-1, -1}, coords2, #, Bottom}, 
  {{2, 0}, coords5, #, Bottom}, 
  {{0, 1}, coords2, #, Top}, 
  {{-1, 0}, coords5, #, Top}, 
  {{1, -1}, coords3, #, Right}, 
  {{-1, 2}, coords3, #, Left}} & @ LightGray;
```

The picture above generated using:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  MapApply[texturedPolygon[TranslationTransform[#] @ #2, #3, #4] &]@
   Join[magenta, yellow, gray]}, 
  Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Large]
```

> picture at the top

**Variations:**

```
SeedRandom[123]; 

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  MapApply[texturedPolygon[TranslationTransform[#] @ #2, ##3] &] @ 
  (Join[magenta, yellow, gray] /. _?ColorQ :> RandomColor[])}, 
 Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  MapApply[texturedPolygon[TranslationTransform[#]@#2, ##3] &] @ 
  (Join[magenta,  yellow, gray] /. _?ColorQ :> 
      ColorData["AvocadoColors"][RandomReal[]])}, 
 Background -> Black, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, kglr, a perfect replica

Answer (score 6):

**Gestalt-Bleu**

- I don't konw how to control the color.
- One idea is that we find the projection of 3D to 2D which projecte `{1,0,0}` to `{1,0}`, `{0, 1, 0}` to `AngleVector[π/3]=={Cos[π/3],Sin[π/3]}` etc..
- We set the 3D coordinates as below.

[image]

```
Clear[tran,sol];
tran[{x_, y_, z_}] := {{a, b, c}, {p, q, r}} . {x, y, z};
sol = Solve[{tran@{1, 0, 0} == {1, 0}, 
     tran@{0, 1, 0} == AngleVector[π/3], tran@{0, 0, 0} == {0, 0},
      tran@{0, 0, 1} == AngleVector[(2 π)/3]}][[1]];
tran[{x_, y_, z_}] = tran[{x, y, z}] /. sol;

subdivideRectangle[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_}] := Module[{m, n, e1, e2},
  m = Norm[p2 - p1];
  n = Norm[p4 - p1];
  e1 = Normalize[p2 - p1];
  e2 = Normalize[p4 - p1];
  Table[{Polygon[
     tran /@ {p1 + x*e1 + y*e2, p1 + x*e1 + y*e2 + e1, 
       p1 + x*e1 + y*e2 + e1 + e2, p1 + x*e1 + y*e2 + e2}]}, {x, 0, 
    m - 1}, {y, 0, n - 1}]
  ]
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Blue],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, 0, 4}, {4, 0, 4}, {4, 8, 4}, {0, 8, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 0, 0}, {4, 12, 0}, {4, 12, 4}, {4, 0, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 8, 4}, {4, 12, 4}, {4, 12, 8}, {4, 8, 8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 8, 4}, {4, 8, 8}, {0, 8, 8}, {0, 8, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 8, 8}, {4, 12, 8}, {0, 12, 8}, {0, 8, 8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 8}, {0, 12, 8}, {-4, 12, 8}, {-4, -4, 
     8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 4}, {0, 8, 4}, {0, 8, 8}, {0, -4, 8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4}, {0, -4, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 0}, {8, -4, 0}, {8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}, {8, 12, 0}, {4, 12, 0}}]
  }]
```

[image]

- If I set some color rule, but they does not conforms to the original image.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
tran[{x_, y_, z_}] := {{a, b, c}, {p, q, r}} . {x, y, z};
sol = Solve[{tran@{1, 0, 0} == {1, 0}, 
     tran@{0, 1, 0} == AngleVector[π/3], tran@{0, 0, 0} == {0, 0},
      tran@{0, 0, 1} == AngleVector[(2 π)/3]}][[1]];
tran[{x_, y_, z_}] = tran[{x, y, z}] /. sol;
subdivideRectangle[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_}] := Module[{m, n, e1, e2},
  m = Norm[p2 - p1];
  n = Norm[p4 - p1];
  e1 = Normalize[p2 - p1];
  e2 = Normalize[p4 - p1];
  Table[{Blend[{Darker@Blue, White}, (x + y)/(m + n)], 
    Polygon[tran /@ {p1 + x*e1 + y*e2, p1 + x*e1 + y*e2 + e1, 
       p1 + x*e1 + y*e2 + e1 + e2, p1 + x*e1 + y*e2 + e2}]}, {x, 0, 
    m - 1}, {y, 0, n - 1}]
  ]
Graphics[{
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, 0, 4}, {4, 0, 4}, {4, 8, 4}, {0, 8, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 0, 0}, {4, 12, 0}, {4, 12, 4}, {4, 0, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 8, 4}, {4, 12, 4}, {4, 12, 8}, {4, 8, 8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 8, 4}, {4, 8, 8}, {0, 8, 8}, {0, 8, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 8, 8}, {4, 12, 8}, {0, 12, 8}, {0, 8, 8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 8}, {0, 12, 8}, {-4, 12, 8}, {-4, -4, 
     8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 4}, {0, 8, 4}, {0, 8, 8}, {0, -4, 8}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4}, {0, -4, 4}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{0, -4, 0}, {8, -4, 0}, {8, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}],
  subdivideRectangle[{{4, 0, 0}, {8, 0, 0}, {8, 12, 0}, {4, 12, 0}}]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, cvgmt, the geometry is more complicated than I thought