# Vera Molnár's interruptions - erasing graphic elements

Tags: graphics, regions, random, generative-art

**Vera Molnár**

Vera Molnár (1924 - 2023) was a Hungarian artist who, like [Victor Vasarely](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297922/reproducing-two-of-victor-vasarelys-colored-cuboids-eroed-per-and-gestalt-bleu), lived and worked in France. She was one of the
pioneers of computer graphics. Trained as a traditional artist, she produced combinatorial images from as early as 1959, *"imagining I had a computer"*, a method she referred to as *"machine imaginaire"*.

[image]

*Vera Molnár in 1961*

In 1968, Molnár created her first computer graphics, and in 1976 she developed "Molnart", a graphics software written in Fortran. Her work has been widely collected by major museums, including MoMA, Tate and Centre Pompidou. Vera Molnár died on 7 December 2023, at age 99.

*"I have no regrets. My life is squares, triangles, lines"*, she once remarked.

**Quatre éléments**

One of Vera Molnár's first digital works, created in 1968, was "Quatre éléments distribués au hasard" ("Four randomly distributed elements").

[image]

*Vera Molnár, Quatre éléments distribués au hasard, 1968*

My replication attempt with Mathematica was surprisingly simple.

```
a = Line[{{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}}];
b = Line[{{i, j + 1}, {i + 1, j}}];
c = Line[{{i + 0.5, j}, {i + 0.5, j + 1}}];
d = Line[{{i, j + 0.5}, {i + 1, j + 0.5}}];

SeedRandom[0];

Framed[
 Graphics[{
   Thickness[0.0075],
   Table[RandomChoice[{a, b, c, d}], {i, 25}, {j, 25}]},
  Background -> GrayLevel[0.95]],
 Background -> GrayLevel[0.95]]
```

[image]

**Interruptions (1968-1969)**

In this series, Molnár starts with a grid covered with straight lines of the same length, and applies a random rotation to each, generating a densely complex pattern. To this, she adds *"interruptions"*, random sections in which certain lines are erased. *"Interruptions"*, was produced with a mainframe computer using her own program, which she entered into punch cards and printed on a plotter.

[image]

*Vera Molnár, Interruptions, 1968*

To reproduce the lines wasn't too difficult, but I have no idea how to produce the random erasure patterns.

```
SeedRandom[0];

Framed[
 Graphics[{
   GrayLevel[0.0],
   Thickness[0.002],
   Table[
    Rotate[
     Line[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}],
     RandomInteger[{0, 180}] Degree],
    {i, 40}, {j, 40}]}],
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]]
```

[image]

**My question**

How can I "inject" the erased patterns? Please also have a look at the other works of the series [interruptions](https://dam.org/museum/artists_ui/artists/molnar-vera/interruptions/) to see what I would like to reproduce: One or two large erasures or several smaller ones. The problem is complicated by the fact, that erased areas might still contain small "islands" of lines.

Comment: Thank you for making my morning browse that much more interesting 

Comment: You are most welcome, thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- We define the rotated lines by `RotationTransform` in order to keep the lines be the `Region`.
- We use `RegionDisjoin`  to erase the lines.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[0];
lines = Flatten[
   Table[RotationTransform[RandomInteger[{0, 180}]  Degree, 
      Mean[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}]]@
     Line[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}], {i, 40}, {j, 40}], 1];
contour = BezierCurve[{{0, 20}, {10, 30}, {20, 20}, {10, 10}}];
reg = FilledCurve[contour] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics;
Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.0], 
  Thickness[0.002], {EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], reg}, 
  Select[lines, RegionDisjoint[reg, #] &]}]
```

[image]

- Use random curve.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[0];
lines = Flatten[
   Table[RotationTransform[RandomInteger[{0, 180}]  Degree, 
      Mean[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}]]@
     Line[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}], {i, 40}, {j, 40}], 1];
contour = BezierCurve[RandomReal[{10, 30}, {100, 2}]];
reg = contour // DiscretizeGraphics;
Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.0], Thickness[0.002], {EdgeForm[], FaceForm[]}, 
  Select[lines, RegionDisjoint[reg, #] &]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the second solution gives a Molnár-like result

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example using a random walk.

First we create all the lines. Then we delete lines along a random path:

```
SeedRandom[9];
n = 40;(*original number of lines: n^2*)
nd = 150; (*approx. number of deleted lines*)
dat = Table[
   Rotate[Line[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}], 
    RandomInteger[{0, 180}]  Degree], {i, n}, {j, n}];
pos = Round[Length[dat]/2] {1, 1};
getrand := {t = RandomReal[1, 2]; 
   Which[t[[1]] < 0.4, -1, t[[1]] < 0.8, 1, True, 0], 
   Which[t[[2]] < 0.4, -1, t[[2]] < 0.8, 1, True, 0]};
Do[dat = 
   Delete[dat, pos += getrand; 
    If[pos[[1]] < 1 || pos[[1]] > Length[dat] , pos[[1]] = 1; 
     Continue[]]; 
    If[pos[[2]] < 1 || pos[[2]] > Length[dat[[pos[[1]]]]], 
     pos[[2]] = 1; Continue[]]; pos], {i, nd}];

Framed[Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.0], Thickness[0.002], dat}], 
 FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.8]]
```

[image]

Further, you may broaden the random path. And you may play with SeedRandom to get different patterns.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
And trying to reproduce some of the [interruptions](https://dam.org/museum/artists_ui/artists/molnar-vera/interruptions/) ... :

[image]

by using:

```
interruptions2[rx_ : 1, ry_ : 2, n_ : 20, dx_ : 40, dy_ : 40 ] := 
 Module[{e = 1.3, r = 3, f = .9, t = .03, pts, lines, scaled, 
   exclusions, img},
  lines = Flatten[Table[{{i, j}, {i + e, j + e}}, {i, dx}, {j, dy}], 1];
  img = Image[
    Graphics[
     Table[{Thickness[t], 
       Circle[RandomReal[dx, {2}], {RandomReal[rx], 
         RandomReal[ry]}]}, {n}]], ImageSize -> {100, 100}];
  pts = PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect[img, 2], 1];
  scaled = Partition[Threaded[{r, r}] + f  dx   Rescale[pts], {2}];
  exclusions = NearestTo[scaled, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]@lines;
  Rotate[Line@#, RandomInteger[{0, 180}]   Degree] & /@ Select[lines, FreeQ[exclusions, #] &]]

  Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.5],
    interruptions2[1, 1, 20, 50, 50]
    , Translate[interruptions2[.1, 4, 10, 50, 40], .5 + {22, 8} ]
    , Translate[interruptions2[2, 1, 1, 50, 8], {62, 3} ]
    , Translate[interruptions2[7, .2, 10, 50, 50], .5 + {82, 0} ]
    }, ImageSize -> {1200, 800}]
```

**Original:**
Just an alternative using `NearestTo` in order to filter out the lines based on the proximity to some exclusion points (edges of an image for example ..).

```
interruptions[pts_] := Module[{d = 40, r = 5, lines, scaledpts, exclusions}, 
  lines = Flatten[Table[{{i, j}, {i + 1.3, j + 1.3}}, {i, d}, {j, d}] , 1];
  scaledpts = Partition[
       Threaded[RandomReal[{-r, r}, 2] + {d/4, d/4}] + d/2  Rescale[pts], {2}];
  exclusions = NearestTo[scaledpts, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]@lines;
  Graphics[Rotate[#, RandomInteger[{0, 180}]  Degree] & /@ 
    Line /@ Select[lines, FreeQ[exclusions, #] &], ImageSize -> Small]]

Multicolumn[
  interruptions@
    PixelValuePositions[
     EdgeDetect[Image@Rasterize@Magnify[#, 15], 1], 1] & /@ 
{"", "",  "", "", "", "☘️"}, 3]
```

[image]